# $P(|X - Y| \leq 1/2)$, $X$ and $Y$ have continuous uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> $X \sim Unif[0, 1]$ and $Y \sim Unif[0, 1]$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Determine $P(|X - Y| \leq 1/2)$.

Thoughts:

Let $Z = X - Y$. Then $Z = X + (-Y)\sim Unif[-1, 1]$ with constant pdf = $1/2$. Then, we have $P(|Z| \leq 1/2) = P(0 \leq Z \leq 1/2) = (1/2)^2 =1/4$.

Is this correct? I'm not sure I can determine the distribution of $Z$ so simply.

Comment: Why would the sum be uniform? Just compute the area of $[|X-Y| \le {1 \over 2}]$.

Comment: The sum would be uniform because the intervals are different. There is no overlap. How would one go about computing that area?

Comment: My question was rhetorical...

Comment: Well, it makes intuitive sense at least. Why is it wrong?

Comment: There are "more" pairs of numbers near the $X-Y=1$ line than $X-Y=0$ or $X-Y=2$.

Comment: Understood why my intuition was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to find the PDF for $Z=X-Y$. The correct way is this:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(u+z) f_Y(u) du$$

But as pointed out in the comments, there is an efficient way to do it. Consider the set $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. We want to find the probability of picking a point $(x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$ such that $|x-y| \le 0.5$. So all you need to do is find the area of the region $|x-y| \le 0.5$ that is inside the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and divide it by the area of the square (which is $1$).

Edit: This proposition makes sense because the distribution of both $X$ and $Y$ is uniform.

Comment: Wouldn't the integrand of the convolution be $f_X(z - u)f_{-Y}(u)$?

Comment: No. What I have written is correct.

Comment: Well, the problem requires the pdf of $-Y$ not of $Y$. Okay, they are the same, but still - why $(z + u)$ then $(u)$? I have never seen a convolution formula like that. It's always $(z  - u)$ then $(u)$.

Comment: I could write up a formal proof for it but that makes it two questions. I'd suggest you go back and look at your notes/recommended probability reference and I am sure you will find a formal proof there. If you have any problems understanding the proof, you re welcome to post that here in a separate question and you'll get help.

Comment: The distribution of $Z$ is $1+z$ between -1 and 0, and $1-z$ between 0 and 1; 0 otherwise. It is a triangle, then you can compute the area between $-1/2$ and $1/2$. The formula as in @Vizag has $f \equiv 1$, you just have to put in the correct interval of integration for $z<0$ and $z>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment:**  You're on the right track.

The points $(X,Y)$ are uniformly distributed in the square with
vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1).$ In the figure below (drawn using
simulation in R), the blue region shows the proportion of points
with $\{|X - Y| < .5\}.$ Seems to be $3/4.$

```
x = runif(10^5); y = runif(10^5)  
event = abs(x-y) < 1/2
mean(event)
[1] 0.7492

plot(x,y, pch=".")
  points(x[event],y[event], col="blue", pch=".")
  abline(v = .5, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note::* Even though the problem can be solved by using elementary
school algebra and geometry, it may be useful to evaluate
the appropriate double integral. If you do that, it's probably
best to split the interval into two parts--to the left of the
vertical red line and to the right.

Comment: Very cool simulation sir. This is super helpful given that I use R.